# Outlook VBA Runtime Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, outlook

This macro works fine when used on a "clean" new email. However when I reply or forward an email, I get the VBA

> error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

```
Private WithEvents olRemind As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Set olRemind = Outlook.Reminders

If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Task" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

If Item.Categories <> "Online" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

SetOnline

Timed_box (1)

Pause 30

SetOffline

Item.MarkComplete

Set olRemind = Outlook.Reminders
    For Each objRem In olRemind
            If Item.Categories = "Online" Then
                If objRem.IsVisible Then
                    objRem.Dismiss
                    Cancel = True
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next objRem

End Sub

'Categorize Sent Items
'Place in ThisOutlookSession
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Len(Item.Categories) = 0 Then
        Set Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
    End If
End Sub
```

`Set Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` is the line I need to debug. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the reply or forward is in the pane at the bottom of Outlook, the `ActiveInlineResponse` pane. I recently modified some code to take that pane into account. If that's the case, something like this might work for you:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Len(Item.Categories) = 0 Then
    If Not Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse Is Nothing Then
        Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
    End If
    'If the draft is in it's own window
    If OutItem Mail Is Nothing Then
        If Not Application.ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then
        Set Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is untested, and I might not have pasted/modified everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Item is passed to ItemSend, you need not find it yourself.

```
'Categorize Sent Items
'Place in ThisOutlookSession
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Len(Item.Categories) = 0 Then
        Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
    End If
End Sub
```